# Get Content from a Label in ListBox.DataTemplate

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

I'm trying to get the Label.Content inside a ListBox.DataTemplate as described in title, my problem is that in all the ways I've tried all gave error, below is my code.

xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="UsersList" Margin="644,50,50,31.999" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Background="White">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="50" Width="654" MouseEnter="SetHashUser">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label x:Name="HashUser" Content="{Binding Path=USER_HASH}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Uid="RealAcessoUserDisplay" Text="{Binding Path=NOME}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Uid="RealAcessoUserDisplay" Text="{Binding Path=NIVEL_ACESSO}" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0"/>
                        <Menu Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="2">
                            <MenuItem Header="Ativar"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Desativar"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Detalhes" Click="ShowUser"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Editar"/>
                        </Menu>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

DB Connection C#

```
        private void Listtks()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BellaContext"].ConnectionString;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT USER_HASH,NOME,NIVEL_ACESSO FROM USUARIOS";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        UsersList.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
```

My goal is when clicking on an item in the list, the SelectedRow gets the User_Hash.Content.

Event:

```
    private void SetHashUser(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        display.Content = UsersList.SelectedItem(HashUser.Content);
    }
```

Error:

```
Error:

error CS0103: The name "HashUser" does not exist in the current context
error CS1955: The non-callable member "Selector.SelectedItem" can not be used as 
a method.
```

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow`, can you give us the error you get or what you're expecting to happen?

Comment: Thanks, I added now

Comment: Use SelectionChanged event of ListBox instead of Click or MouseEnter you have used inside the template. First error is because there is no method in your code behind with the name 'HashUser'. Second error is because SelectedItem is a property. It is DataRow, cast & get the value from it.

Comment: please show a example.

Answer (score 1):

ListBox SelectedItem is not a method. It is property which gives the selecteditem of the listbox. In this case the selecteditem will be DataRow since you bind DataTable to ListBox.

Assuming USER_HASH as string. Try below code.

```
private void SetHashUser(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataRow = UsersList.SelectedItem;
        display.Content = dataRow.Field<string>("USER_HASH ");
    }
```

Comment: Error CS1929: "Object" does not contain a definition for "Field" and a better overload of the "DataRowExtensions.Field <String> (DataRow, string) extension method" requesting a receiver of type "DataRow"

Comment: i need get Content in Label x:Name="USER_HASH"